# Aggregate by week in R

Tags: r, aggregate, zoo

In R I frequently aggregate daily data (in a `zoo`) by month, using something like this:

`result <- aggregate(x, as.yearmon, "mean", na.rm=TRUE)`

Is there a way that I can do this by week?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is to use the `apply.weekly` function from `xts`.

```
> apply.weekly(zoo(1:10, as.Date("2010-01-01") + 1:10), mean)
2010-01-03 2010-01-10 2010-01-11 
         3         42         10
```