# Aggregate Weekly Data in R

Tags: datetime, r

I am sure this is straight forward but I just cant seem to get it to work.  I have a data frame that represents daily totals.  I simply want to sum the totals by week, retaining a zero if a week is not represented.  What is the best approach in R?  In case it matters, I read the data in from a CSV and converted it to a date once in R.

Here is the structure of my data frame p1:

```
'data.frame':   407 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ date:Class 'Date'  num [1:407] 14335 14336 14337 14340 14341 ...
 $ amt : num  45 150 165 165 45 45 150 150 15 165 ...
```

and the first few...

```
> head(p1)
        date amt
1 2009-04-01  45
2 2009-04-02 150
3 2009-04-03 165
4 2009-04-06 165
5 2009-04-07  45
6 2009-04-08  45
```

Many thanks in advance.

One note:  I saw one previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4309248/aggregate-by-week-in-r) but couldn't get it to work

Comment: Try converting your data to a `zoo` or `xts`. Also, please post the command you're trying and the bad output it gives. I think if you follow Shane's guidance, and also set `na.rm=T` after the `"sum"` that it should spit back `NaN` for weeks that are all `NA`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution that reads in the data, aggregates it by week and then fills in missing weeks with zero all in 3 lines of code.  `read.zoo` reads it in assuming a header and a field separator of comma.  It converts the first column to `Date` class and then transforms the date to the following Friday.  The `nextfri` function that does this transformation taken from the `zoo-quickref` vignette in the zoo package.  (If you want to have the end of week be a different day of the week just replace *every* 5 in the formula with another day number.  The idea is that relative to the UNIX Epoch that d-4 falls on day of the week d where d=0 is Sunday, d=1 is Monda, ..., d=6 is Saturday so any multiple of 7 days from that also falls on day of the week d.)  The `read.zoo` command also aggregates all points that have the same index (remember that we have transformed them to the last Friday of the week so all points in the same week will have the same Friday as their index now).   The next command creates a zero width zoo object that has the weeks from the first to the last and merges that with the output of the read using `fill = 0` so that the filled in weeks get that value.

```
Lines <- "date,amt
2009-04-01,45
2009-04-02,150
2009-04-03,165
2009-04-13,165
2009-04-14,45
2009-04-15,45"
library(zoo)
nextfri <- function(x) 7 * ceiling(as.numeric(x - 5 + 4)/7) + as.Date(5 - 4)
z <- read.zoo(textConnection(Lines), header = TRUE, sep = ",", 
    FUN = as.Date, FUN2 = nextfri, aggregate = sum)
merge(z, zoo(, seq(min(time(z)), max(time(z)), 7)), fill = 0)
```

We used `textConnection(Lines)` above to make it self contained so that you can just copy this and paste it right into your session but in reality `textConnection(Lines)` would be replaced with the name of your file, e.g. `"myfile.csv"` .

For the input above the output would be the following zoo object:

```
2009-04-03 2009-04-10 2009-04-17 
       360          0        255
```

There are three vignettes that come with the zoo package that you might want to read.

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for!  Two things:  I am getting an error because I suspect that it is that my "dates" in the CSV file are day/month/year.  I saw in the help that I can pass this as a format "%d/%m/%Y" but I am not sure if that is causing the error.  Secondly, I would like the week to end on Sunday with Monday starting a new week.  Thanks again!

Comment: This is really unnecessary since library(zoo) is already used and the subsequent lines would not work without zoo.  If you want to take that line out of context and make it independent of zoo you can just specify the origin= argument explicitly.

Comment: *If you want to have the end of week be a different day of the week just replace 5 with another day number.* - I am slightly confused about this - actually I think the `-5+4` is a constant (and can be replaced with -1) - ??? (see my answer, which I posted because too much code for a comment)

Comment: I have clarified in the answer that both instance of 5 must be replaced.

Comment: From a comment by G.Grothendieck himself on a (now deleted) post of mine: *For Sunday replace both instances of 5 with 0: like this: nextsun <- function(x) 7 * ceiling(as.numeric(x - 0 + 4)/7) + as.Date(0 - 4) and note that as.Date(0-4) is a Sunday*

Answer (score 5):

A solution with the `lubridate` library:

```
library(lubridate)
Lines <- "date,amt
2009-04-01,45
2009-04-02,150
2009-04-03,165
2009-04-13,165
2009-04-14,45
2009-04-15,45
2009-05-15,45"
df <- read.csv(textConnection(Lines))
```

If you don't need 0 for missing weeks it's simple:

```
weeks <- week(df$date)
sums <- tapply(df$amt, weeks, sum)
# 14  15  16  20 
#360 210  45  45
```

To put zeros for missing weeks:

```
span <- min(weeks):max(weeks)
out <- array(0, dim = length(span), dimnames = list(span))
out[dimnames(sums)[[1]]] <- sums
# 14  15  16  17  18  19  20 
#360 210  45   0   0   0  45
```